# How to avoid "KeyError: 'None of [2001] are in the columns'" when setting index to pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` called `maximoVerano` and want to reindex it as I will append other DataFrames with different year indexes. However when I want to use `set-index` as you can see in the sample example I get the error code:

> KeyError: 'None of [2001] are in the columns'

### Sample code

```
>>> maximosVerano
   demanda  demanda31.5  ...  fechaHoraMaxDem31.5   fechaHoraMaxDem63
0   28.037       4.1211  ...  2001-03-16 21:00:00 2001-01-15 22:00:00

[1 rows x 6 columns]
>>> type(maximosVerano)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
>>> maximosVerano.index
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=1, step=1)
>>> maximosVerano.set_index([anio], inplace=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4727, in set_index
    raise KeyError(f"None of {missing} are in the columns")
KeyError: 'None of [2001] are in the columns'
>>> anio
2001
```

### Question

How can I set the index to the `DataFrame` and get as index 2001 in this simple case?
Be aware that the type for the index is originally a range. Maybe the issue is there but I'm unsure.

Comment: Check [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for `set_index()` carefully: "Set the DataFrame index _using existing columns_." (emphasis mine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `maximosVerano.index=[anio]`

`set_index()` is a function for setting a column as the new index of a dataframe. For setting the index, you can use simple assignment

```
df=pd.DataFrame(index=[0], columns=[1,2,3],data=[[1,2,3]])

df
    1   2   3
0   1   2   3

anio=2001

df.index=[anio]

df
        1   2   3
2001    1   2   3
```

Comment: You do not demonstrate the technique from your answer. Change the answer to match the demonstration.

Comment: This solution works. However I still don't understand why I can't use `set_index`

Comment: @JedMitten I don't understand your criticism. `anio` is clearly a variable with the value of `2001` from the error posted in the question. So my answer demonstrates how to set a single-row dataframe index with a numeric value. I've edited for clarity though

Comment: @CedricZoppolo that function is for setting an _existing column_ as the new index. For example, if you called `set_index('demanda')`, then the column `demanda` would be set as the index for the dataframe. Because you're trying to assign a new value, that is not the method to use in your case

Answer (score 0):

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html

`set_index` is expecting the `keys` parameter to be `label or array-like or list of labels/arrays`. You are telling it to use the index labeled `2001` (as `anio` = `2001`)

Try:

```py
maximosVerano.set_index("anio", inplace=True)
```

or

```py
maximosVerano.set_index(["anio"], inplace=True))
```

Comment: This assumes `"anio"` is found in `maximosVerano.columns`

Comment: This suggestion doesn't work. It shows the same error message

Comment: "This assumes "anio" is found in maximosVerano.columns" that is exactly why the `KeyError` is being thrown. Because the value of that variable doesn't exist in the columns. Also, "You are telling it to use the 2002nd column as the index" is incorrect. It's trying to find a column labelled `2001` and set that as the index. It's named, not positional

Comment: @G.Anderson thank you for the correction - I updated to reflect that the index is named, not positional

Comment: @CedricZoppolo, perhaps because you tried both of my proposed answers you got a `KeyError` again. After the first `set_index` operation, the index is updated  (due to `inplace=True`) so there is no longer a column named `anio`.